# Interim analysis and alpha spending in group sequence design of clinical trials

Tags: experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, clinical-trials, type-i-and-ii-errors

In group sequential design, does the type of interim analysis affect the alpha spending for each look?

I tested in ADDPLAN, with two interim analyses, specifying "stopping for futility" or not does not affect the alpha spent on the interim analyses.

I only tested Pocock's design and O'Brien/Fleming's design. Not sure if this is true for other sequential designs.